# multiple stopwatch in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stopwatch

[image]

I want to make multiples stopwatches in jquery, but the problem is i want the stopwatch the respective stopwatch to sun when we hit the corresponding button, and should stop when we hit button for another stopwatch and that respective stopwatch should start simultaneously, please see the image for reference, i know the question is not so clear, sorry for inconvenience.

thanks in advance.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any question, let alone it being unclear

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask], and remember to always include a [mcve] in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    (function($){

        $.extend({

            APP : {                

                formatTimer : function(a) {
                    if (a < 10) {
                        a = '0' + a;
                    }                              
                    return a;
                },    

                startTimer : function(dir) {

                    var a;

                    // save type
                    $.APP.dir = dir;

                    // get current date
                    $.APP.d1 = new Date();

                    switch($.APP.state) {

                        case 'pause' :

                            // resume timer
                            // get current timestamp (for calculations) and
                            // substract time difference between pause and now
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime() - $.APP.td;                            

                        break;

                        default :

                            // get current timestamp (for calculations)
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime(); 

                            // if countdown add ms based on seconds in textfield
                            if ($.APP.dir === 'cd') {
                                $.APP.t1 += parseInt($('#cd_seconds').val())*1000;
                            }    

                        break;

                    }                                   

                    // reset state
                    $.APP.state = 'alive';   
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Running');

                    // start loop
                    $.APP.loopTimer();

                },

                pauseTimer : function() {

                    // save timestamp of pause
                    $.APP.dp = new Date();
                    $.APP.tp = $.APP.dp.getTime();

                    // save elapsed time (until pause)
                    $.APP.td = $.APP.tp - $.APP.t1;

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Resume');

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'pause';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Paused');

                },

                stopTimer : function() {

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');                    

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'stop';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Stopped');

                },

                resetTimer : function() {

                    // reset display
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms,#' + $.APP.dir + '_s,#' + $.APP.dir + '_m,#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html('00');                 

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Start');                    

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'reset';  
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Reset & Idle again');

                },

                endTimer : function(callback) {

                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');

                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'end';

                    // invoke callback
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback();
                    }    

                },    

                loopTimer : function() {

                    var td;
                    var d2,t2;

                    var ms = 0;
                    var s  = 0;
                    var m  = 0;
                    var h  = 0;

                    if ($.APP.state === 'alive') {

                        // get current date and convert it into 
                        // timestamp for calculations
                        d2 = new Date();
                        t2 = d2.getTime();   

                        // calculate time difference between
                        // initial and current timestamp
                        if ($.APP.dir === 'sw') {
                            td = t2 - $.APP.t1;
                        // reversed if countdown
                        } else {
                            td = $.APP.t1 - t2;
                            if (td <= 0) {
                                // if time difference is 0 end countdown
                                $.APP.endTimer(function(){
                                    $.APP.resetTimer();
                                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Ended & Reset');
                                });
                            }    
                        }    

                        // calculate milliseconds
                        ms = td%1000;
                        if (ms < 1) {
                            ms = 0;
                        } else {    
                            // calculate seconds
                            s = (td-ms)/1000;
                            if (s < 1) {
                                s = 0;
                            } else {
                                // calculate minutes   
                                var m = (s-(s%60))/60;
                                if (m < 1) {
                                    m = 0;
                                } else {
                                    // calculate hours
                                    var h = (m-(m%60))/60;
                                    if (h < 1) {
                                        h = 0;
                                    }                             
                                }    
                            }
                        }

                        // substract elapsed minutes & hours
                        ms = Math.round(ms/100);
                        s  = s-(m*60);
                        m  = m-(h*60);                                

                        // update display
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms').html($.APP.formatTimer(ms));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_s').html($.APP.formatTimer(s));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_m').html($.APP.formatTimer(m));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html($.APP.formatTimer(h));

                        // loop
                        $.APP.t = setTimeout($.APP.loopTimer,1);

                    } else {

                        // kill loop
                        clearTimeout($.APP.t);
                        return true;

                    }  

                }

            }    

        });

        $('#sw_start').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.startTimer('sw');
        });    

        $('#cd_start').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.startTimer('cd');
        });           

        $('#sw_stop,#cd_stop').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.stopTimer();
        });

        $('#sw_reset,#cd_reset').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.resetTimer();
        });  

        $('#sw_pause,#cd_pause').live('click', function() {
            $.APP.pauseTimer();
        });                

    })(jQuery);

});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/V2S9d/897/)

**OR**

```
$(function () {

    // Never assume one widget is just used once in the page. You might
    // think of adding a second one. So, we adjust accordingly.
    $('.stopwatch').each(function () {

        // Cache very important elements, especially the ones used always
        var element = $(this);
        var running = element.data('autostart');
        var hoursElement = element.find('.hours');
        var minutesElement = element.find('.minutes');
        var secondsElement = element.find('.seconds');
        var millisecondsElement = element.find('.milliseconds');
        var toggleElement = element.find('.toggle');
        var resetElement = element.find('.reset');
        var pauseText = toggleElement.data('pausetext');
        var resumeText = toggleElement.data('resumetext');
        var startText = toggleElement.text();

        // And it's better to keep the state of time in variables 
        // than parsing them from the html.
        var hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, timer;

        function prependZero(time, length) {
            // Quick way to turn number to string is to prepend it with a string
            // Also, a quick way to turn floats to integers is to complement with 0
            time = '' + (time | 0);
            // And strings have length too. Prepend 0 until right.
            while (time.length < length) time = '0' + time;
            return time;
        }

        function setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) {
            // Using text(). html() will construct HTML when it finds one, overhead.
            hoursElement.text(prependZero(hours, 2));
            minutesElement.text(prependZero(minutes, 2));
            secondsElement.text(prependZero(seconds, 2));
            millisecondsElement.text(prependZero(milliseconds, 3));
        }

        // Update time in stopwatch periodically - every 25ms
        function runTimer() {
            // Using ES5 Date.now() to get current timestamp            
            var startTime = Date.now();
            var prevHours = hours;
            var prevMinutes = minutes;
            var prevSeconds = seconds;
            var prevMilliseconds = milliseconds;

            timer = setInterval(function () {
                var timeElapsed = Date.now() - startTime;

                hours = (timeElapsed / 3600000) + prevHours;
                minutes = ((timeElapsed / 60000) + prevMinutes) % 60;
                seconds = ((timeElapsed / 1000) + prevSeconds) % 60;
                milliseconds = (timeElapsed + prevMilliseconds) % 1000;

                setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
            }, 25);
        }

        // Split out timer functions into functions.
        // Easier to read and write down responsibilities
        function run() {
            running = true;
            runTimer();
            toggleElement.text(pauseText);
        }

        function pause() {
            running = false;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            toggleElement.text(resumeText);
        }

        function reset() {
            running = false;
            pause();
            hours = minutes = seconds = milliseconds = 0;
            setStopwatch(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
            toggleElement.text(startText);
        }

        // And button handlers merely call out the responsibilities
        toggleElement.on('click', function () {
            (running) ? pause() : run();
        });

        resetElement.on('click', function () {
            reset();
        });

        // Another advantageous thing about factoring out functions is that
        // They are reusable, callable elsewhere.
        reset();
        if(running) run();
    });

});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/8qmyg/551/)

Comment: thanks but i want single interval and function for multiple stopwatches, i do not want to write functions and set intervals multiple times

Comment: SEE this link https://www.sitepoint.com/online-jquery-stopwatch/ @shivchhabra

Comment: thanks @Ivin raj using your answer i will try to code this myself, it was a help, thanks.

Comment: welcome sir @shivchhabra